# Return index number of matching item in array

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In Excel, how can I return the index number for a matching item in an array?

For example, if one column has:

Apple
Pear
Zebra

and I ask for "Pear", the function should return the numeric value 2. If I ask for "Grape", it should return FALSE or #N/A.

None of the spreadsheet functions I researched (Lookup, VLookup, Match) do this.

Comment: `Match` does exactly what you need. Please share how you've tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the function **MATCH** does exactly that.

Say you have

```
Apple
Pear
Zebra
```

in **A1:A3**.

Your input is in **D1**, and output in **D2**.
**D1** will have some word, and **D2** should be:

```
=MATCH(D1,A1:A3,0)
```

Where **D1** is the value you are searching, **A1:A3** is the column you are searching in, and **0** means you are looking for a perfect match.

D2 will output the index of the value specified in D1, or #N/A if it is not it the list.